# syntax error near unexpected token `AX_VALGRIND_CHECK'

Tags: valgrind, autoconf, m4

I am trying to integrate valgrind into my unit test framework by using the following m4 macro described at https://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf-archive/ax_valgrind_check.html. In my configure.ac I have

```
AC_CONFIG_MACRO_DIR([m4])
...
AX_VALGRIND_DFLT()
AX_VALGRIND_CHECK
```

I have placed the [.m4 script](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/gitweb/?p=autoconf-archive.git;a=blob_plain;f=m4/ax_valgrind_check.m4) provided, in both ./m4 and in /usr/share/aclocal. To generate the configure script etc, I run the following:

```
aclocal && autoconf && autoreconf --no-recursive --install && \
autoheader && libtoolize --force && automake --force-missing \
--add-missing
```

However when I go an run `./configure` I get the following error

```
./configure: line 12914: syntax error near unexpected token `AX_VALGRIND_CHECK'
./configure: line 12914: `AX_VALGRIND_CHECK'
```

What do I need to do to get my configure script to work with the macros provided by the [.m4 script](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/gitweb/?p=autoconf-archive.git;a=blob_plain;f=m4/ax_valgrind_check.m4) above. I am not sure what other information to provide.

---

Below is my configure.ac. I will try to find at which point things break using this configure.ac vs the one generated by `autoreconf -i` as posted by @Kusalananda.

```
AC_INIT([binary_balanced], [0.1], [mehoggan@gmail.com])                        
AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE([-Wall -Werror foreign subdir-objects])                       
AC_CONFIG_SRCDIR([./src/])                                                     
AC_CONFIG_HEADERS([config.h])                                                  
AC_CONFIG_MACRO_DIR([m4])                                                      
AC_PROG_CC                                                                     
AM_PROG_AR                                                                     
AM_PATH_CHECK                                                                  

LT_INIT                                                                        

# Checks for programs.                                                         
AC_PROG_CC                                                                     

# Checks for libraries.                                                        
AX_VALGRIND_DFLT()                                                             
AX_VALGRIND_CHECK                                                              

# Checks for header files.                                                     

# Checks for typedefs, structures, and compiler characteristics.               

# Checks for library functions.                                                

AC_CONFIG_FILES([Makefile                                                      
                 src/Makefile                                                  
                 tests/Makefile])                                              
AC_OUTPUT
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can not re-create your problem.

I also very seldom run anything other than `autoreconf -i`.  This will re-run the other autotools as needed.

I put the `ax_valgrind_check.m4` into a `./m4` directory and created a stub `configure.ac`:

```
AC_PREREQ([2.69])
AC_INIT([test],[0.0.0-dev])
AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE([foreign])
AC_CONFIG_MACRO_DIR([m4])
AX_VALGRIND_DFLT()
AX_VALGRIND_CHECK
```

Running `autoreconf -i` creates a `configure` script that does the following:

```
$ ./configure
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /Users/kk/sw/bin/ginstall -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /Users/kk/sw/bin/gmkdir -p
checking for gawk... gawk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking whether make supports nested variables... yes
checking for valgrind... no
```

So the macros are picked up (which they weren't in your case).

So, run `autoreconf -i` to see if that sorts things out for you.

If you can't get this to work, try installing the `autoconf-archive` package for whatever Unix you're on.  It will also contain this macro.